# Out-File creating empty blank line at end

Tags: powershell

Good afternoon, all.

I am trying to run the following command and get rid of the very last empty line.I have found things on here such as `(command | out-string.Trim()` I believe it is, and I just can't get anything I do to remove the last line.

Here is the simple code I am trying to run:

```
gwmi win32_quickfixengineering | 
    sort installedon -desc | 
    ?{$_.InstalledOn -gt [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-30)} | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty HotFixID | 
    Out-File C:\OUTPUT\FILE.txt -Force
```

If you run that command, you will see it displays the info as I need, but then adds an extra line at the bottom I can't get rid of.

I also tried `Export-CSV` as an option to try and get comma delimited data, but I can't get that to work either. It just returns "Length", "9", "5" or something to that affect.

If the Export-CSV can be figured out to add the "," delimiter in there, that would be fantastic!

Thanks all

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`-NoNewLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-5.1#-nonewline) but first you need to convert the output to a single string joined by new line characters:

```bash
(Get-CimInstance win32_quickfixengineering |
    Where-Object { $_.InstalledOn -gt [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-30) } |
    Sort-Object InstalledOn -Descending |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty HotFixID) -join [Environment]::NewLine |
    Out-File C:\OUTPUT\FILE.txt -NoNewline
```

Instead, what I recommend you is to output to a Csv and for this, it is as easy as removing `-ExpandProperty` from your code, then your Csv will have `HotFixID` as a header and there is no need to worry about ending with a new line:

```bash
Get-CimInstance win32_quickfixengineering |
    Where-Object { $_.InstalledOn -gt [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-30) } |
    Sort-Object InstalledOn -Descending |
    Select-Object HotFixID |
    Export-Csv C:\OUTPUT\FILE.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Using the output to the .txt file worked like I am looking for. No new line at the end at all whatsoever. The output to a csv file still puts an CR at the end of the file, which I need to avoid. With using that output to the .txt file option, how would I be able to instead of put them one a separate line, separate them by a comma and/or pipe "|" instead?

Comment: @CharlesWaters you want a single line all joined by `|` ?

Comment: Yes, that would work. As long as it saves with no lines above or below the saved file. That's the issue I am running in to.